# Gradle Release System Task - Calling uploadArchives on subprojects

Tags: continuous-integration, gradle

In order to release my system, I am creating a releaser project that calls uploadArchives for a number of other projects.

In my project I have the following files:

**settings.gradle**

```
include '../proj-a',  '../proj-b'
```

**build.gradle**

```
task releaseSystem() {
     // what goes here?
}
```

What should the contents of the releaseSystem task be such that I can call `gradle releaseSystem` and have it run uploadArchives for each of my sub projects?

I've tried a number of options, but none have been successful thus far.

Thank you for any insights you can provide.

**ANSWER**

I'm continually impressed with the graceful solutions gradle provides to my problems.  Here's my final solution (as Peter pointed out below):

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'proj-a',  'proj-b'
project (':proj-a').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../proj-a')
project (':proj-b').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../proj-b')
```

**build.gradle**

```
task releaseSystem() {
    dependsOn {
        [
            subprojects.build,
            subprojects.uploadArchives
        ]
    }
}
```

Note, that since my repository is a maven repository, when I originally included '../proj-a' in my settings.gradle, it produced poms with artifactId ../proj-a which was invalid.  I had to change my settings.gradle to the format above for the system to put the poms together correctly and for the uploadArchives task to complete successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all subprojects have an `uploadArchives` task:

```
task releaseSystem {
    dependsOn { subprojects.uploadArchives }
}
```

Note that this won't run the subprojects' tests.

Comment: I'm continually impressed with how graceful gradle is.  Thank you for the answer.  One additional problem in my case.  My repositories are maven repositories, so when running in this fashion it creates invalid pom files because the artifactId has "../" proceeding it.  Any way around this?

Comment: i found a way around this problem by using the projectDir settings.  will update the question above.  thanks again